# How to pass a very long list in jdbcTemplate spring-boot

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using oracle datasource which does not allow more than 1000 records in a query.

My idList contain 10K or more which would be dynamic

My unit test  is

```
@Test
    public void testLongListParameter(){
        String QUERY = "select value from sample_table where id in (:ids)"; 
        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
        Map idMap = Collections.singletonMap("ids", idList);
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(QUERY, idMap, new CustomRowMapper());

    }
```

when I run this I get `ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000`

so the problem is I have more argument than limit of oracle. to resolve this do I have to write my custom query generator or does spring already have something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Everything must use the JDBC API in the end...and the limit there is `100` for `SELECT` lists. Anything bigger than that is not guaranteed to be supported by the database. You've hit the limit on Oracle, but it could have been some other vendor also.

There is really nothing you can do there on that regard.

On a different realm, hacking the solution, you can:

1. Split the `IN` clause into several `OR`'ed chunks (up to you for the chunk size, you can go with `100` or `1000` since you know that's the limit you hit)
2. Insert the dataset into a temporary table, then use a sub-query in the `IN` clause